# URL routing and relative paths

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, relative-path

Let's say, the default controller is root.php then both URLs will work

```
website.com/
website.com/root
```

if controller has a function named *login* then this URL is also valid

```
website.com/root/login
```

but the HTML template that used to work in first example, doesn't work in the second, e.g. this relative path is no longer valid

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/style.css'/>
```

and instead for `website.com/root/login` I have to use a different path

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../stylesheets/style.css'/>
```

even though I'm in the same controller and trying to use the same stylesheet.

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the browser is looking for the stylesheets relative to the url in the address bar.

so the in the case of the  first stylesheet in the second url, ie:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/style.css'/> @ website.com/root/login
```

The browser is looking for the file at

```
website.com/root/stylesheets/styles.css
```

Which is not where the files are kept. I assume they are actually at `website.com/stylesheets/styles.css`.

The easiest way around this is to simply make all the paths relative to the root of the website.

so if you try this, you should find that it works.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
```

Comment: Embarrassingly simple. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but what if you can't use absolute paths. Say if your development box is run in root, but the application is hosted in a virtual directory on the server?

Answer (score 2):

If your development environment is located in a subdirectory (example: `htdocs/myWebSite/`), but your production website is not in a subdirectory, then simply using `/stylesheets/style.css` will make migrating back and forth between the two versions of your website incredibly painful, as you'll have to go through every such link and add/subtract the `/myWebsite` from each of them.

A possible solution to that is to define a global variable in your code that represents your root directory, and then use that variable at the start of all your links. For example:

```
$BASEurl = "http://localhost/myWebsite";
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$BASEurl/stylesheets/style.css'>";
```

Then, when you're uploading the project to your production server, simply change the value of $BASEurl to `http://www.nameOfYourDomain.com`, and you're good to go.

Comment: This is a genius workaround, keep changing my path from my development env to my website is a lot of pain in the ass as you said. Thanks man.